# How to achieve this using XmlSerializer?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-tv

I am trying to achieve this line:

`<icon src="http://storage.googleapis.com/android-tv/images/gmail.png" />`

Using XmlSerializer in Android Studio(android TV).
I've managed to put start and end tags, but the result becomes this:

`<icon> src="http://storage.googleapis.com/android-tv/images/gmail.png" </icon>`

What i have to do to get it like the one shown above?

Comment: are you trying to get the link  http://storage.googleapis.com/android-tv/images/gmail.png only? because what you get is already what you want

Comment: Why don't you just append it on start and end "<"+url+">" like this ? Also both the links are the same right ?icon tag is closed differently that's all..

Comment: What's wrong with the second line? Both are the same and correct xml.

Comment: I'm using Android TV Sample app, and their xmlParser uses the src link as an icon to display. I think it's trying to read the link, but is it the same meaning and functionality as the second line? <icon /> is the same as <icon></icon>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. 
By using `serializer.startTag` then `serializer.attribute` and then closing the tag `serializer.endTag`.

This will create the wanted result. The difference shows when adding `serializer.text` instead of `serializer.attribute`, the ending of the tags change.